# Need my image to be assign like honeycomb with HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/czX8U.png]

*I have an hexagon images,i need to arrange like honeycomb,top-3 bottom 2 images with responsive.How to achieve this using css *

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
            <figure class="overlay overlay4 light"><a href="#"></a> <img src="style/images/service/tele1.png" alt="" />
             
            </figure>
       </div> 
 
 <div class="col-md-4">
            <figure class="overlay overlay4 light"><a href="#"></a> <img src="style/images/service/broad.png" alt="" />
             
            </figure>
          
  </div>  
   
   <div class="col-md-4">
            <figure class="overlay overlay4 light"><a href="#"></a> <img src="style/images/service/broad.png" alt="" />
             
            </figure>
         
 </div>  
 
 <div class="col-md-4">
            <figure class="overlay overlay4 light"><a href="#"></a> <img src="style/images/service/broad.png" alt="" />
             
            </figure>
          
 </div> 
 
  <div class="col-md-4">
            <figure class="overlay overlay4 light"><a href="#"></a> <img src="style/images/service/broad.png" alt="" />
             
            </figure>
        </div>
```

Comment: it could be helpful to you https://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/wWGeEM?editors=1010

Comment: i am already having hexagon images separately,i need to arrange top 3 and bottom2 images.i need help in that

Comment: then check the link @KalaiselvanA provided!

Comment: @VidhyaVidu  try like this https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/BJdeoR

Comment: thank you kalaiselvan. Got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be helpful to you!

https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/BJdeoR

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-4">
            <figure class="overlay overlay4 light"><a href="#"></a> <img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Hexagon-PNG-Clipart.png" alt="" />
             </figure>
</div> 
 
<div class="col-md-4">
            <figure class="overlay overlay4 light"><a href="#"></a> <img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Hexagon-PNG-Clipart.png" alt="" />
            </figure>
</div>  
   
<div class="col-md-4">
            <figure class="overlay overlay4 light"><a href="#"></a> <img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Hexagon-PNG-Clipart.png" alt="" />
    </figure>
</div>  
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-12">
   
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
            <figure class="overlay overlay4 light"><a href="#"></a> <img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Hexagon-PNG-Clipart.png" alt="" />
            </figure>
</div> 
 
<div class="col-md-4">
            <figure class="overlay overlay4 light"><a href="#"></a> <img src="http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Hexagon-PNG-Clipart.png" alt="" />
            </figure>
</div> 
   <div class="col-md-offset-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of ***clip-path*** css property to create honeycomb shape of images.
You can go through the code explained here:

It is possible to create masking effect usign clip-path property in CSS. Apply this style on every image used. It crops the image and appears as - image inside in a Hexagonal container.

```
figure img{
width:200px;height:200px; float:left;display:inline-block;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 27%, 100% 76%, 50% 100%, 0 76%, 0 27%);
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 27%, 100% 76%, 50% 100%, 0 76%, 0 27%);
}
```

You can find the code executed here:
https://codepen.io/UI-UXDeveloper/pen/zpdVvr

Comment: this is ok.i need responsive one